# Upgrading from a wildcard app ID to an explicit app ID to allow push notifications

Tags: app-store, wildcard, explicit, app-id, file-in-use

I have an app that has about 300,000 members and I would like to add push notifications to it. Unfortunately I originally created the app with a wildcat bundle id `com.MyCompany.*` and when I uploaded it to Apple and when I edited it in my `plist` file I made it say `com.MyCompany.MyAppName`

Now that I want to add push notifications I have to make a unique (or EXPLICIT) app ID so I attempted to make one called `com.MyCompany.MyAppName` ... I got this error message: `The bundle identifier you have specified is already in use. Please select another.`

I looked at my app ids and all I have is `com.MyCompany.*`. So it's not anything I can delete. The message must be referring to the live version of my app that is already out there using the wildcard app ID...

How do I convert from my wildcat app id to an explicit app id so I can send push notifications to members?

I've searched the web for about 2 hours now and everyone seems to say that all you have to do is create a new app ID that has the same bundle ID as your current live version of the app... so I'm guessing this error message `The bundle identifier you have specified is already in use. Please select another.` is a new error message that didn't exist until very recently because no-body else seems to have experienced this problem...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i have a same issue. waiting for solution :(

Comment: I know nothing about this, but am guessing maybe the * doesn't match another path element.  So could you say `com.MyCompany.MyAppName.NewAndCool.UniqueId`?  Sorry if this is a ridiculous suggestion.

Comment: I try doing that, (instead of the asterisk, using the unique version that was assigned) and Apple says it's already in use and I can't do that... ?? /: I'm just going to have to call them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple automatically switched all of my wildcards over to explicit IDs during December 2012. I didn't have to call them!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use "MyCompany" in your bundle identifier you need to use something like com.apple.preferences or com.apple.maps. the company has to be your own name or company name so my one is com.oogemaflip100.preferences or com.oogemaflip100.maps.

Comment: That was for the sake of demonstration.