# unable to create a new app id for an iOS app originally submitted with a wild card app id

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, in-app

I have been stuck spinning my wheels on a problem and thought I'd see if someone can help. 
Have you ever added in-app notifications to an app that was already on the app store? I am trying to add in-app notifications to an existing app.  fyi...in case this matters it was approved by apple but I have given it future release date since I did not want people downloading it until I came up with another version with more features.

I found the following link on stackoverflow [Updating live App ID for Push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840754/updating-live-app-id-for-push-notifications)
I followed the instructions from the link above that said I had to create a new App Id with the same bundle id as my existing app since in-app notifications can not use a wild card app id. But I can not create the new app id with the existing apps bundle id.  I get the error message below. 
An App ID with Identifier com.myappname is not available. Please enter a different string.
Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new App Id. You need to add Push notification service to your existing App Id. Note that you will have to use the provisioning profile that uses your App Id explicitly i.e. you can't use provisioning profile that uses wildcard app Id. If you are already using a provisioning profile that uses your App Id then you can continue to use that one.

Comment: You replied: you can't use provisioning profile that uses wildcard app Id.  The problem is that my app was created with a wildcard app id so I can not add in-app notifications.  This means I have to create a new app id. right?

Comment: Try creating the provisioning profile on the apple developer portal. During this it will ask you to select the application id. I think you will see the one with your existing bundle id.

Comment: Ok Rakmoh...I'll give that a try and let you know how I make out

Comment: Rakmoh...if I create a new provisioning profile I am prompted to select an app id.  There is no app id with my bundle id because I never created one. I used a wild card app id. I can select the wild card app id I originally used to create this app for the new provisioning profile but that will not help me since an app id with a wild card can not enable in-app notifications.

Comment: That is strange. Can you confirm that you are trying to create the new  app id (as described in your origin question) with exactly the same bundle id defined in application's info.plist (you can provide extra suffix if you want).

Comment: When I attempt to create a new app id with the bundle id found in both my info.plist and in iTunes connect's manage apps I get the error message  'An App ID with Identifier com.myappname is not available'

Comment: It seems to be the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032507/upgrading-from-a-wildcard-app-id-to-an-explicit-app-id-to-allow-push-notificatio You should also open a radar for this at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting

Comment: Nice find.  He said that apple automatcially switched all of his wildcard ids to explicit id in Dec 12 wohtout him having to call them.  I think I might have to call them.  First I'll try reporting it as a bug like you suggested.